# Wordpress 404 problem

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress blog and I need to add a php file on the website. The problem is whatever php file I upload to the website, I get a Wordpress generated 404 error.

I believe this is a .htaccess or permissions error, but I can't find any fix for it.

File: `.htaccess`

```
# -FrontPage- 
#IndexIgnore .htaccess /.?? ~ *
# */HEADER /README /_vti 
<Limit GET POST>
    order deny,allow deny from all allow from all
</Limit> 
<Limit PUT DELETE> 
    order deny,allow deny from all 
</Limit> 
AuthName doctortipster.com 
AuthUserFile /home/doctips/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.pwd 
AuthGroupFile /home/doctips/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.grp

# BEGIN WordPress 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteBase / 
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
</IfModule> 
# END WordPress
```

Do you have any idea what could cause it?

Thanks

Comment: How does `.htaccess` looks like?

Comment: and where in the document root did you upload the file ?

Comment: I tried adding the file both directly in public_html and in the theme's folder. I have to say this can't be a server issue, because I have many blogs on this server and I only have this problem on this one.

Comment: I added the `.htaccess` file to your main question. Please delete the first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this line:

```
RewriteRule   PATH/TO/YOUR/SCRIPT.php - [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem. The file had 666 permissions. I've set it to 644 and it now works.