# Why does my website give 404 errors for pages that exist and are accessible?

Tags: php, http-status-code-404, google-search-console

My problem is that on certain pages on my website such as http://www.piranha-internet.co.uk/web/website-design.php I am been served with a 404 error in Google Webmaster Tools.  However I can access the pages normally, they all have links pointing to them internally, non yet from external.

- I have done header checks on this page and get served a 404 as well.
- I have created blank files on my server and they seem fine giving me a 200 code but if I duplicate and rename the 404 files in question I get the same 404 errors.
- I have roughly 40 pages on my site, half of which give 200 code and half 404. They all use the same structure & same includes but the content is different on all of them.

Why is this happening?

Comment: http://www.piranha-internet.co.uk/web/website-design.php works fine for me

Comment: Step 1 of resolving web server issues: **Check your error log.**

Comment: What does "GWT" mean? Are you using Wordpress?

Comment: Updated post and switched tag.  GWT generally refers to Google Web Toolkit.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem when I tried to include my wordpress header at the top of the code before the HTML

```
<?php
    include('blog/wp-blog-header.php');
?>
```

The pages worked but Google saw a 404 and wouldn't index the pages.

Solved the problem by moving the PHP include inside the body of the HTML.

Weird problem...

Dan

Comment: This was my issue too. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It appears when I visit http://www.piranha-internet.co.uk/web/website-design.php using Fiddler, I get a 404 HTTP status code returned along with the page content.  Somewhere your server, or your code is actually sending a 404 HTTP status code.

Is there a possibility you could show some of your `.php` source code for the relevant pages, such as `website-design.php` and the header include files?

**Edit:**

> Could you try a systematic approach:
>   Start with a blank page, that returns
>   a 200 HTTP code.  Add lines of HTML /
>   PHP from one of those pages that
>   returns a 404, line by line, and keep
>   testing after each change until you
>   find what change sent it to a 404
>   instead of a 200.  See if you can
>   trace it down to a specific line of
>   code, a specific function call,
>   include etc., and post the result.

Comment: @Peter: Is there *anything* different between the pages that work and that don't?  Different `include` statements?  Different calls to different functions?  Could you try a systematic approach: start with a blank page, and a line of code at a time until you get the 404 error, to figure out what is the source?

Comment: @Peter: Does it have anything to do with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542008/wordpress-404-problem.

Comment: it turns out that in the config file I was defining the location of the wordpress header file which I use to display the latest blog posts on the homepage of the website. The other files on the site dont use this so for some reason it was re-writing the header to a 404. dont really know why only half of the pages were erroring... but still its fixed so thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

What you see in GWT is the actual HTTP response code. 404 in your case an it means "Not Found".

By definition this marks the request as "Not found" and that's what GWT reports to you.

Within any PHP script you can set the response code in addition to the output. I have no insight into the code of `/web/website-design.php` so it's hard to tell what's wrong or if it's wrong at all.

You could look for the use of the [header() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) within your code. That function can set the response code.